# IpOverUsb Service Insufficent Privileges

Tags: windows-phone, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to install the Windows 10 IpOverUsb Service for developers. I have Windows 10 on my phone and downloaded the wconnect.rar. When I try to install IpOverUsb it says top check if I have sufficient privileges and I am administrator. Could it be that I need to have Windows 10? I have Windows 7.

I am stuck on this so can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Select "Services" on your PC
2. Select "Windows Phone IpOverUsbSvc"
3. Right-click on it
4. select "Start" or "Restart"